# How to populate a character pointer inside another pointer without using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to assign a character pointer inside another pointer within a struct. My environment has no malloc/calloc therefore dynamic memory allocation is not an option. How would i make it possible to populate the character pointer in read_string_from_byte_array() function ?

```
    typedef struct custom_string
    {
        char textt[5];
        int length;
    }custom_string;

    typedef struct custom_string_container
    {
        custom_string* string;
    }custom_string_container;

    void read_string_from_byte_array(custom_string_container* string_container)
    {
        char* byte_array = "12345";
        int i;

        puts("assigning");
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string_container->string->textt[i] = byte_array[i]; //failing with exit code 139
        }

        puts("done assigning");

    }



    void main()
    {
        //dynamic memory allocation is strictly prohibited
        custom_string_container string_container;

        read_string_from_byte_array(&string_container);
        printf("read string is %s \n", string_container.string->textt);

    }
```

Comment: What warnings do you get?

Comment: You have multiple problems with the code you show. First and foremost you use pointers without initialization (`string_container->string` isn't initialized to point anywhere). Secondly, your `textt` member is an array of *pointers* to `char`, i.e. it could be seen as an array of (possible) strings. Thirdly, you forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* is what all standard string functions use to find the end of a string (which includes the `printf` function with the `"%s"` format specifier).

Comment: Your `char* textt[5]` field is table of five character pointers, so `ttext[i]` is `char*` and `byte_array[i]` is `char` and you are trying to assign `char` to `char*`.

Comment: char* textt[5] was a typo.

Comment: One point of a [mcve] is that we basically should be able to copy-paste it and get the exact same result you get. That includes getting the exact same build warnings and errors you might be getting, and if you don't get any build warnings or errors, make sure the code you show also don't have any, even when enabling more warnings from the compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is the error after crash >>>> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want dynamic allocation in the heap replace

```
typedef struct custom_string_container
{
    custom_string * string;
}custom_string_container;
```

by

```
typedef struct custom_string_container
{
    custom_string string;
}custom_string_container;
```

and of course replace when needed '->' by '.'

also warning with

```
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string_container->string->textt[i] = byte_array[i]; //failing with exit code 139
    }
```

the null terminating char is missing, this is a problem when doing

```
printf("read string is %s \n", string_container.string->textt);
```

if you want to store 5 characters (without counting the null char)
add `string_container->string->textt[i] = 0;` after the *for* or replace `i < 5` by `i <= 5` to also copy the null character

and of course replace `char textt[5];` by `char textt[6];` in `struct custom_string`

Note to write 6 in the size then 5 or 6 elsewhere is dangerous in case you change the size, it is much more secure to use *sizeof*

Finaly with all changes :

```
typedef struct custom_string
{
    char textt[6];
    int length;
}custom_string;

typedef struct custom_string_container
{
    custom_string string;
}custom_string_container;

void read_string_from_byte_array(custom_string_container* string_container)
{
    char* byte_array = "12345";
    int i;

    puts("assigning");
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(string_container->string.textt); i++)
    {
        string_container->string.textt[i] = byte_array[i]; 
    }
    string_container->string.textt[i] = 0;

    puts("done assigning");

}



void main()
{
    //dynamic memory allocation is strictly prohibited
    custom_string_container string_container;

    read_string_from_byte_array(&string_container);
    printf("read string is %s \n", string_container.string.textt);

}
```

Execution :

```
assigning
done assigning
read string is 12345
```

and under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ valgrind ./a.out 
==8507== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8507== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8507== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8507== Command: ./a.out
==8507== 
assigning
done assigning
read string is 12345 
==8507== 
==8507== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8507==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8507==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==8507== 
==8507== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8507== 
==8507== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8507== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

---

Note also that the copy in `read_string_from_byte_array` can be simply done using *strncpy* (not *strcpy* in case `byte_array` is too long to be memorized in *textt*) rather than the *for* loop

Comment: the program is failing when i is zero, it has nothing todo with the null terminator. the program still crashes even after null terminating the last element.

Comment: @salimsaid That's cause `string_container->string` is not initialized.

Comment: @Osiris how would i initialize string_container->string without using malloc ?